# Other Cucumber tests fail after I installed devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, devise

I installed Devise, and all of my cucumber tests are now failing because I require the user to login. This makes sense.

Is there a way to specify that a user is logged in WITHOUT going through a senario such as this:

```
>   Scenario: Create Issue
>     Given I am on the home page
>     When I fill in "Email" with "justin@gmail.com"
>     And I fill in "Password" with "secret"
>     And I press "Sign in"
>     Then I am on the list of issues
```

I tried something like the following: `user_signed_in? = true` but this fails. Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in [this guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Test-with-Cucumber), you can factor out that code into multiple matchers to help reduce duplication. More specifically I'd look at the `Given /^I am a new, authenticated user$/ do` block.

Comment: Thanks for your help! btw do you know if there are any disadvantages to dumping webrat for capybara